# Can not populate array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**EDIT** added mongoose.model.

I'm pretty new to mongodb and mongoose. I'm not able to populate books to authors in mongoose.
Can anyone help me with that? Here is my code. I removed unnecessary fields

```
const authorSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    books: [{
        type: String,
        ref: "Book"
    }]
}, {_id:false})

const Author = mongoose.model('Author', authorSchema)

module.exports = {Author}
```

And my books schema looks as following

```
const bookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true,
        trim: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        unique: true
    },
    description:{
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: 'No description specified'
    },
    datePublished: {
        type: Date,
        trim: true,
        default: '01/01/2001'
    },
    author:{
        type: String,
        ref: 'Author',
        required: true
    }
}, {_id:false})
const Book = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema)

module.exports = {Book}
```

Here is the route to populate them together

```
AuthorRouter.get('/authors/:id', async(req, res)=>{
    const authorID = req.params.id
    try {
        const author = await Author.findById(authorID)
        try {
            const populated = await author.populate({path: 'books.book', select: 'name description -_id'})
            console.log(populated);
            res.status(201).send(populated)
        } catch (e) {
            res.status(401).send(`${e}\n Unable to populate categories`)
        }
        
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).send('Unable to find author')
    }
})
```

Output is following with empty books array:

```
{
    "_id": "123",
    "name": "testuser",
    "books": [],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Where in the code did you specify the [`Mongoose.model`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) function?

Comment: @Tyler2P at the end of the Schemas. I've just added them to code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Populating an arrays of refs works the [same way as a single ref](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population). Just call the populate method on the query and an array of documents will be returned in place of the original `_id`'s.

In your case that would be:

```
const populated = await author.populate({path: 'books', select: 'name description -_id'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey i have modify your code , try to use this one

This is your author schema file

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const authorSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    books: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "bookSchema"
    }]
}, {_id:false})

const Author = mongoose.model('Author', authorSchema)

module.exports = {Author}
```

And this is your route

```
AuthorRouter.get('/authors/:id', async(req, res)=>{
    const authorID = req.params.id
    try {
        const author = await Author.findById(authorID)
        try {
            const populated = await author.find().populate('books');
            console.log(populated);
            res.status(201).send(populated)
        } catch (e) {
            res.status(401).send(`${e}\n Unable to populate categories`)
        }
        
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).send('Unable to find author')
    }
})
```